# Wrong font family in question footer (tags/signature)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, markdown-rendering

There is something about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212344/29) that is messing up the formatting on the page. It seems that something with a fixed-width style is carrying over into the question footer:

[image: Im supposed to say waffles here I guess]

I scanned the markdown briefly for manually entered `<code>` and `<pre>` tags but didn't see any.

Comment: The same I've met today in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/577949)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a space and re-saved and it seems fine.

The body was last edited in August '09 which means it was subject to old Markdown bugs that were since fixed in [MarkdownSharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/).

Comment: welcome to the 100k club, btw. I bet you created meta under the guise of improved community involvement and issue tracking, but really it exists just to give you this opportunity, right?